# how to serialize and deserialize hibernate object?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i want to serailize & deserialized hibernate object.
Can anybody tell me how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `SerializationHelper` utility provided by hibernate, clone will do job for you. but if you want to save as new entity then make sure you reset id and version properties.

[javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/util/SerializationHelper.html)

one typical requirement i have used this to achive snapshot of current state of entity object, refer to my answer in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529237/hibernate-entity-change-revision-history/11537710#11537710)

**Example:**

```
  Entity object=SerializationHelper.clone(<Entity Object>);
```

This method will create clone (new object) by first serializing and then deserializing.

Comment: Ok i got this, but I need sample example for better understanding. Can you help me to provide me any example?